# OnClick passing undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

I am trying to pass an onClick value, but it passes undefined. Works well if it is not a Card/Paper/Div but I need this "button" to be a Card/paper/div

```
onClick={() => this.handleChange('bostadstyp')}
onClick={ value='villa', handleChange('bostadstyp')}

render() {
    const { bostadstyp } = this.props;
    const { auth } = this.props;
    const { value, values, handleChange, handleClick } = this.props;
    const { backgroundColori } = this.props;
    const backgroundColor2 = "#F09515";
    const aa = "";

    // const imageUrl = window.innerWidth >= "1600px" ? Banner1 : Banner2;

    //  {if (!auth.uid) return <Redirect to="/loggain" />;}

    return (
      <div>
        <img
          className="stars3"
          src={Logo}
          width="15%"
          align="center"
          marginBottom="10px"
        />
        <img src={Logo} width="15%" align="center" marginBottom="10px" />
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#F1F1F1", padding: "30px" }}>
          <h2
            style={{
              marginTop: "0px",
              marginLeft: "10%",
              color: "#F09515",
              fontFamily: "Avenir",
              fontWeight: "bold"
            }}
          >
            {" "}
            Dina Preferenser{" "}
          </h2>
        </div>
        <form
          className="background123"
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "#fdfdfd",
            marginTop: "0px",
            marginBottom: "0px"
          }}
        >
          <Card
            className="row xl12 l12 m12 s12"
            style={{
              marginLeft: "10%",
              marginRight: "10%",
              padding: "30px",
              backgroundColor: "#fdfdfd"
            }}
          >
            <br />
            <div className="col xl6 l6 m12 s12">
              <h4
                style={{
                  fontFamily: "Avenir",
                  fontWeight: "bold",
                  color: "#F09515"
                }}
              >
                1. Välj din boendestyp
              </h4>
              <p className="texti" style={{ fontSize: "16px" }}>
                Vi behöver den här uppgift då vissa avtal endast gäller för
                vissa anläggningstyper.
              </p>
            </div>
            <div className="col xl6 l6 m12 s12">
              <Card
                className="row cardi xl12 l12 m12 s12"
                style={{ width: "270%", backgroundColor: `white` }}
                value={"villa"}
                onClick={handleChange("bostadstyp")}
              >
                <div className=" col xl7 l7 m6 s6">
                  <img src={villa} width="50px" />
                </div>
                <div className="col xl5 l5 m5 s5">
                  <h6
                    className="texti"
                    style={{ fontSize: 16, textAlign: "right" }}
                  >
                    Villa/radhus
                  </h6>
                </div>
              </Card>
            </div>
          </Card>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I expect to 'values.bostadstyp' get the value 'villa'

Comment: `onClick={ value='villa', handleChange('bostadstyp')}` isn't correct syntax.

Comment: @Oblicion A where is `handleChange` function defined?

Comment: @AmolBJamkar in the parent component

Comment: @OblicionA can you add `handleChange` code in the question?

Comment: @AmolBJamkar   handleChange = input => e => {
    this.setState({ [input]: e.target.value });
  };

Answer (score 0):

because you are using function in the class so you must using this.handleChange instead of handleChange

```
<Card onClick={() => this.handleChange('bostadstyp' )}>
....
</Card>
```

Comment: Tried this before. The card stops being "clickable" don't know why

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the `onClick()` listener to a `<CardActionsArea/>` component which should be nested inside your `<Card/>` component

Something like

```
<Card className="row cardi xl12 l12 m12 s12" style={{ width: '270%', backgroundColor: `white` }} value={'villa'} onClick={handleChange('bostadstyp' )}  >



                                    <div className=" col xl7 l7 m6 s6">

                                        <img src={villa} width="50px" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="col xl5 l5 m5 s5">

                                        <h6 className="texti" style={{ fontSize: 16, textAlign: "right" }}>Villa/radhus</h6>
                                    </div>
                                </Card>
```

Also, I suggest looking into the `<CardActions/>` documentation, the example [here](https://material-ui.com/components/cards/#simple-card) shows how its used

Comment: liked your approach, but then I got problem like: ×
TypeError: this.handleChange is not a function. (In 'this.handleChange('bostadstyp')', 'this.handleChange' is undefined).

Comment: it is weird actually because it works fine with radio button or any other type of input. Just the cards and divs gives this error

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code in your card element:

```
<Card className="row cardi xl12 l12 m12 s12" 
                style={{ width: '270%', backgroundColor: `white` }} value={'villa'}
                onClick={(e) => {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  this.handleChange('bostadstyp');
                }}>
```

The issue may be due to one of the below reasons:
1. handleChange() not bound with this.
2. To pass values from onClick handler you should use (e) => func('value')
3. The click is happening inside form element, its better to include event.preventDefault()

Comment: liked your approach, but then I got problem like: × TypeError: this.handleChange is not a function. (In 'this.handleChange('bostadstyp')', 'this.handleChange' is undefined).

Comment: Of course you need to define handleChange(param) inside your class.

Comment: Secondly, you expect to update 'values.bostadstyp' which has been passed from props. React recommends not to set props values direclty. You should define a state variable named 'values' and set values inside it.

Comment: all the secondary variables (in this case 'values') are defined within "state" as react recommends!

Comment: `onClick={(e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let values = {...this.state.values};
  values["bostadstyp"] = "villa";
  this.setState({ values });
}}` This will work and you can also move setState code inside handle method.

Comment: This means 'values' has not been initialised inside constructor. Can you share your constructor block?

Answer (score 0):

You need user [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):
`onClick={() => { this.handleChange('bostadstyp' ) }}`

```
<Card className="row cardi xl12 l12 m12 s12" style={{ width: '270%', backgroundColor: `white` }} value={'villa'} onClick={() => { this.handleChange('bostadstyp' ) }}  >
    <div className=" col xl7 l7 m6 s6">
        <img src={villa} width="50px" />
    </div>
    <div className="col xl5 l5 m5 s5">
        <h6 className="texti" style={{ fontSize: 16, textAlign: "right" }}>Villa/radhus</h6>
    </div>
</Card>
```

[image: Edit Material UI]

**UPDATE**
Handle Change from parent component:

[image: Edit Material UI]

Comment: tried, it does not work. it returns the error: ×
TypeError: this.handleChange is not a function. (In 'this.handleChange('bostadstyp')', 'this.handleChange' is undefined).

handleChange is defined in the parent component

Comment: I had the same approach on the parent component. I adapt the onClick={{ this.props.handlechange. Does not work. It stops being clickable

Comment: @OblicionA replace `{{` with => `{`

Comment: your solution works if you define the value to be passed before. I need it to pass value of the card on the onClick

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your `handleChange` is bound properly by explicitly binding it or using an arrow function syntax:

```
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this) // In component's constructor

// or

handleChange = (value, input) => {
  this.setState({
    [input]: value
  });
};
```

2. `onClick` expects a function to invoke, so you need to wrap your handler into one:

```
<Card onClick={() => handleChange('villa', 'bostadstyp')}></Card>
```

Comment: the handleChange is binded by handleChange = input => e => {
    this.setState({ [input]: e.target.value });
  };

tried your solution, the card stops being clickable (nothing happens)

Comment: It has to be `handleChange = (e, input) =>{ this.setState({ [input]: e.target.value }); };` without an extra function wrapped. And then `onClick={(e) => handleChange(e, 'bostadstyp')}`. Updated the answer.

Comment: it gives me the error TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.target.value')

Comment: Right, this is not an input element, so that code won't work. You need to pass the value directly. Updated the answer.

Comment: I am really sorry being boring you. Now I get the infinite loop error: "×
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops."

Comment: do you modify state in `componentDidUpdate`?

Comment: No! I do not even use componentDidUpdate in the all code!

Comment: So where do you define `handleChange` then?

Comment: in the parent component……

Comment: Make sure you wrap onclick in a function the way it's in the answer.